# R 3.1.3 How to Scrape Multiple City-Data.com Records?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I'm trying to use R to scrape the city-data.com data for a couple of hundred California cities and have it return a nice table (rows=cities, columns=city variables) from the website.  I'd like to be able to input a list of URLs, one for each city.  Right now I can come close to scraping a single city URL for a single record using:

```
library(XML)
city.url = c("http://www.city-data.com/city/Acalanes-Ridge-California.html"
city.df = readHTMLTable(city.url, header=T, which=2, stringsAsFactors=F)
head(city.df,1)
```

It returns:
 Males: 568 (50.0%)
1 Females: 569 (50.0%)

I'd really appreciate any advice.  Dollar General is trying to build in our community and I'm trying to quickly put together an impact analysis to examine what happens to small towns after a Dollar General is built.  Thanks!

Comment: if you have a list of urls, you can use loop (like `lapply`) to extract all.

Comment: Thanks!  Would it look something like this? 
city.df = lapply(city.urls, readHTMLTable(city.urls, header=T, which=2, stringsAsFactors=F))

Comment: You are close: `lapply(urls,readHTMLTable,header=T, which=2, stringsAsFactors=F)` or `lapply(urls,function(i)readHTMLTable(i,header=T, which=2, stringsAsFactors=F)) ` will do.

Comment: Nice.  Thank you!  That solves the question of multiple URLs.  Now I'll need to figure out how to pull different variables from each URL into the same data frame.  Cheers!

Comment: No problem. Are you asking another question?

Comment: I think so.  Each city's web page has multiple pieces of data.  With the existing code, I can extract the second piece of data (which=2).  I need to know how to get the other pieces of data into the same table.  If it's impossible, I think I can just collect the data for a single variable and then stitch is together with the data for each other variable, but it would be nice to have the code pull it all of the variables into one table.

Comment: how many pieces of data are inside each url?If you want all pieces, just remove `which=2`. If you want second and third pieces, use `which=c(2,3)`, and so on.

Comment: Like 20-30.  I can pull multiple variables by making which=1:20.  But, it doesn't look like it returns them in a structured way.

Comment: It returns a list (say k), and if you want first piece, you can just use  k[[1]],

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I think I see.  However, if I print a subset of the list (e.g. list[[1]]), I get all of the variables for the first city, rather than the first variable for all cities.

Comment: You can get the first variable as `k[[1]][,1]` or `k[[1]][,"namesofvar"]`.

Comment: Do you have permission to scrape the site? If not, you (and anyone who assists you) are in violation of _LICENSE AND ACCESS TO THE SERVICE_ in their ToS